# Firebase Authentication backendError code 99

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-identity-toolkit

I have a web app that uses Firebase Authentication for login. Recently, users of the app have been unable to authenticate due to an error emitted from Google's APIs.

Upon sending the request to
`https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/getProjectConfig?key=...&cb=...`

an error is returned:

```
{  
   "error":{  
      "errors":[  
         {  
            "domain":"global",
            "reason":"backendError",
            "message":"Error code: 99"
         }
      ],
      "code":503,
      "message":"Error code: 99"
   }
}
```

According to https://status.firebase.google.com/, Firebase Authentication is good to go. I've also tried migrating to a new Firebase project, but the error persists.

What is the meaning of this error code, and how may it be resolved?

Comment: This was a temporary hiccup that had been immediately fixed. You should not be seeing this anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I checked again and the error is gone.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error when trying to attach second (alternative) firebase project to the application (for development). It turns out that I forgot to upload APNs Auth Key which was required for authorization with phone number (in my case predefined testing number)

> Upload your APNs authentication key to Firebase. If you don't already
>   have an APNs authentication key, see Configuring APNs with FCM.
>
> 1. Inside your project in the Firebase console, select the gear icon, select Project Settings, and then select the Cloud Messaging tab.
> 2. In APNs authentication key under iOS app configuration, click the Upload button.
> 3. Browse to the location where you saved your key, select it, and click Open. Add the key ID for the key (available in Certificates,
>      Identifiers & Profiles in the Apple Developer Member Center) and click
>      Upload.

You can find details about the solution under the following link:

[Authenticate with Firebase on iOS using a Phone Number](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth)

Comment: Hello @kodelit, I am also facing the same issue while I am doing Authenticate with Firebase on iOS using a Phone Number. I uploaded a APNS certificate. problem is that it working fine in the simulator but not working in a real device. I am getting an error :"An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.". please let me know if you find any solution for that.